# JCombox setSelectedItem() causing loss of focus in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I was implementing a auto completion combobox in a `JTable`, everything seems to work fine, but when I fire `model.setSelectedItem(item);` to select the current Item in the combo-list, the combobox loses focus.

Can we override this function?

Comment: Your question title says that JTable looses focus and your text says combobox looses focus. Which is correct?

Comment: Jcombox within the Jtable looses the focus.

Comment: @Akash whatever doesn't matter, canditate for SSCCE http://sscce.org/, but maybe someone has new battery in magic Globe

Answer (score 0):

In your case you shouldn't use `JCombobox#setSelectedItem.` This method call will raise an ActionEvent which might cause the focus to go over to the next component. Try to use instead

```
JCombobox combo = ...
combo.getModel().setSelectedItem(...);
```

**Update:** I reviewed the implementation's code and it seems that using `JComboboBox#setSelectedIndex` is what you are looking for. This method is also used when you type a character and the list shows the next item starting with the typed character.

Comment: this too causes the same behaviour